# Local variation of normals on Riemannian submanifolds of $\mathbb R^D$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry, geometric-probability

Let $M^d\subseteq\mathbb R^D$ be a compact manifold, $p\in M$ and $\nu\in N_p(M)$. Suppose that all the principal curvatures in direction $\nu$ are in $[a,b]$ for some $0<a<b<\infty$. Suppose $\delta>0$ is small enough and $e\in \mathbb R^D$ a uniformly random unit vector. Suppose that $p_e\in M$ is the point closest to $p$ such that $\nu+\delta e\in N_{p_e}(M)$; can we find an upper bound on $E\big[\|{p_e}-p\|\big]$, where $E$ denotes expectation?